# Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently i use

`wp_generate_password('8',false);`

This generate password like:

1. n2ytPbQR
2. Vb2WrA7h

It should be made up of numbers and uppercase English letters such as:

1. N2YTPBQR
2. VB2WRA7H

How can I achieve this in WordPress

Comment: `strtoupper(wp_generate_password('8',false))`?

Comment: All uppercase is reducing your security.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the likelihood of letters and numbers as they were originally, you can transform the result of `wp_generate_password()` to uppercase string, but also adding the numbers explicitly to double their occurence:

```php
strtoupper(wp_generate_password(8, false, '0123456789'))
```

If you don't care about the likelihood between letters and numbers, simple uppercase will do:

```php
strtoupper(wp_generate_password(8, false))
```